# Tunneling through 2 VPN's

Tags: vpn, ubuntu

My university has recently instituted a no public VPN policy (basically to stop piracy) and I was busted for it but managed to scape off without any fines by pleading ignorance (my school *really* loves to fine people). So here is a question: I have a home ubuntu server that I have set up as a PPTP VPN server (which is allowed by my university because it goes through my home and doesnt hide my identity), and a PIA VPN that I use for some other stuff. Would it be possible to have PIA routed through my home VPN (effectively faking my school out). I would need to do this in a way that the server data is not routed through PIA, and hopefully have it so that I can choose whether to use PIA or not (because sometimes I just need to fix my parents stuff).

TL;DR: I need to route my traffic through 2 different VPN's

Comment: What is the need for a VPN?

Comment: how is this a security question? sound more like a configuration issue

Comment: Not sure why you'd need two VPNs at the same time but it is indeed a network configuration question which can be done with proper routing and firewall rules.

Comment: SSH into your box at home (or use as a poor man's VPN) and from there have a VPN running?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60871/vpn-tunnel-inside-other-vpn-tunnel

Answer (score 0):

So chaining two VPNs behind each other? Right?
You could for example configure a VPN in a Virtual Machine, and another one on your normal host OS.

If you operate from your Virtual Machine, you're using two different VPNs.